# Empty return in non-void function, is undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, standards

After reading answers about the topic of *control reaches end of non-void functions* I didn't see any answer adressing specifically the the case of exiting a non-void function with an empty `return` statement:

```
int return_integer() { return; }  // empty return in non-void function
```

What I've found so far in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) is:

> ### 6.8.6.4 The return statement
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1. A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

The standard quote states what **should** we do with our `return` statements for `void` and non-`void` functions, what happens when we ignore the constraint is mentioned in other part of the document:

> ### 6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> 12. If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Previous standard quote states that UB happens if we use the returned value from a function which ends after reaching the closing curly braces (`}`), so we have UB in the code below:

```
int UB(int x) { if (x) return x; }

printf("%d", UB(1)); // Correct
printf("%d", UB(0)); // Undefined behavior
```

In the `UB(1)` call the function returns `1` through the `return x;` instruction under the `if (x)`; in the `UB(0)` call the `if (x)` condition is not passed so function ends reaching `}`, to use the return value in this case is UB (but isn't in `UB(1)`). But, what happens in this case?

```
int UB(int x) { if (x) return; } // empty return statement

printf("%d", UB(1)); // Undefined behavior?
printf("%d", UB(0)); // Undefined behavior
```

In the code above, the call `UB(1)` does not meet the `§6.9.1/12` requirements to lead to UB because the function ends **without reaching `}`** and also does not return any value.

In which part of the C standard is this situation described?

Comment: It violates the "shall" in 6.8.6.4 and therefore it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch I can somehow agree with that but `§6.8.6.4` doesn't mention UB, only states what should be done not what happens if the restriction is not followed.

Comment: Violating a "shall" invokes undefined behaviour. I cannot find the paragraph in the standard, but I remember that I read it some time ago.

Comment: If you return but don't actually store the non-returned value, I don't know offhand whether it is UB or not. But it's a pointless thing to do. If you attempt to assign it it is UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int UB(int x) { if (x) return; }
```

This is not even undefined behavior, it is a *constraint violation*. The cited text

> A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a
>   function whose return type is void

from 6.8.6.4 is normative, meaning the compiler is not allowed to let it slip without giving a diagnostic message. If it compiles without giving a diagnostic, the compiler is not a conforming implementation (doesn't follow the language standard).

In plain English this means: that code should not even compile.

Now if the compiler does produce a binary executable even if the code had constraint violations, all bets are off. It is no longer a C program, but some non-standard one, with no guaranteed behavior by any language standard.

Comment: The standard isn't perfectly clear about what the behaviour is of code that contains a constraint violation, other than a diagnostic must be printed.  In particular it doesn't say that an executable should not be generated, and doesn't say what happens if execution never reaches the area with the constraint violation.